# Error generated while creating table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am writing following statement to create a table in oracle database but failed to create table. An error is generated called

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

I had written following code to create table in oracle

> create table SYSTEM.tUserLogin (Online number(1) null , Role varchar2(15) null )

I am using Oracle 10g express edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should never ever create objects in the `SYSTEM` or `SYS` schema.  You should always create a new schema for user-defined objects.  In addition to being much cleaner, various functionality works differently than you might expect in those two schemas-- they are designed to contain only objects that Oracle provides.
2. `ONLINE` is a reserved word in Oracle so you can't use it as a column name (well, you could if you started using case-sensitive identifiers, but you really don't want to).  You'll need to specify a different name for your column.